# Error when building GCC Android x86 - cpu-features.h not found

Tags: android, gcc, mobile, cocos2d-x, marmalade

I am creating a mobile game using Cocos2d-X 2.2.6 and Marmalade SDK 7.8.0, however when I try to build my project using the GCC x86 Android configuration (both in debug and in release modes), I get the following error:

```
Error    458    error : cpu-features.h: No such file or directory (col 26)    \third_party\cocos2d-x-2.2.6\cocos2dx\platform\third_party\marmalade\libwebp\dsp\cpu.c    17    1    IgualOuDiferente_vc11
```

I can successfully build my project for x86 debug and release and for GCC ARM debug and release. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is possible to comment out the lines that are stopping the build. Full answer here: https://answers.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/34358/error-when-building-gcc-android-x86-cpu-featuresh.html.